# nextTick error with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, yahoo-api

I'm trying to test out a Yahoo API found in this [site](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/exchangepartforoauthcredentials.html). However I can get a "request token" I can't seem to figure out how to proceed since my application `throws process.nextTick` error

Also if possible somehow can help share some code on how to make the request code based on the site provided above. Here's my implementation below:

```
var request = https.request({
    host: "api.login.yahoo.com",
    port: 443,
    method: "GET",
    path: "/oauth/v2/get_token?"
        + "&oauth_consumer_key=abc123--"
        + "&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT"
        + "&oauth_nonce=123456"
        + "&oauth_timestamp=1204762971"
        + "&oauth_signature=abc12345%26"
        + "&oauth_version=1.0"
        + "&oauth_token=" + requestToken
}, function(res){
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        util.log('OAUTH CREDENTIALS: ' + chunk);
    })
});
```

**Error:**

```
Error: socket hang up
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Comment: what exactly does the nextTick error say?

Comment: What's the actual error thrown?

Comment: You should add `request.on('error', function(err){ console.log(err); /* handle error better */});`. Otherwise the error propagates up to `process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {/* handle error better */});` and if not handled there causes the process to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the API was not activated to access any Yahoo services, from the site API management I activated one now it works, how silly.